# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django-Banking-App.settings' when migrating my Django app to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have been trying for two days to deploy my django app to heroku but stuck with the modulenotfound error. Think it might have something to do with my static files but I am not sure. I would forever appreciate someone helping me out with this
Here is the error:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ bb-bank... up, run.4227 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 82, in wrapped
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 254, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django-Banking-App.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 343, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 232, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 226, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django-Banking-App.settings'
```

Arrangement of my files
[image]

wsgi file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Django-Banking-App.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Installed Apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'transactions'
]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Django-Banking-App.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Django-Banking-App.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Added more information

Please tell me if I have left out anything. Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: It's hard to tell what this error could be just because there's so much that can't been seen over SO. A few things: Can you run locally? Can you post your "installed apps"? Also, are you using a .gitignore?

Comment: It runs locally and I don't have a .gitignore file. Added more info too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got around it. Think the error was in naming the application Django-Banking-App. Changed it to just Banking and didn't get the error again

Comment: This was going to be my next comment. Standard convention would be something like `djangobankingapp`. When naming things, try to avoid characters as much as possible because characters mean a lot of different things to programming languages.